# Extract path from lines in a file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract path from a given file which meet some criteria:
Example:
I have a small file with contents something like :

```
contentsaasdf /net/super/file-1.txt othercontents...
data is in /sample/random/folder/folder2/file-2.txt  otherdata...
filename  /otherfile/other-3.txt somewording
```

I want to extract the path's from file which contain **file-*.txt** in it.

In above example, I need the below path's as output

```
/net/super/file-1.txt
/sample/random/folder/folder2/file-2.txt
```

Any suggestions with Python code ?
I am trying regex. But facing issues with multiple folder's, etc. Something like:

```
 FileRegEx = re.compile('.*(file-\\d.txt).*', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Try [`r'\s(/.*?/file-\d+\.txt)\s'`](https://regex101.com/r/5F2sBj/1) with `re.findall`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `.*` just use character classes properly:

```
r'[\/\w]+file-[^.]+\.txt'
```

`[\/\w]+` will match any combinations of word characters and `/`. And `[^.]+` will match any combination of characters except dot.

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/ytsZ0D/1

Note that this regex might be kind of general, In that case, if you want to exclude some cases you can use `^` within character class or another proper pattern, based on your need.

Comment: But the path can contain spaces, digits, etc. As it is a file, sometimes the path could be absolute/relative or can contain variables like $HOME/path/file-1.txt

Comment: @KarthikJeganathan Indeed, I'm just trying to show you the door, but you're the one that has to walk through it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filenames are white-space separated ...

```
\\s(\\S+/file-\\d+\\.txt)\\s
```

- `\\s` - match a white-space character
- `\\S+` - matches one or more non-whitespace characters
- `\\d+` - matches one or more digits
- `\\.` - turns the `.` into a non-interesting period, instead of a match any character

You can avoid the double backslashes using r'' strings:

```
r'\s(\S+/file-\d+\.txt)\s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

re.findall('/.+\.txt', s)
# Output: ['/net/super/file-1.txt', '/sample/random/folder/folder2/file-2.txt', '/otherfile/other-3.txt']
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = """contentsaasdf /net/super/file-1.txt othercontents...
... data is in /sample/random/folder/folder2/file-2.txt  otherdata...
... filename  /otherfile/other-3.txt somewording"""
>>> 
>>> re.findall('/.+\.txt', s)
['/net/super/file-1.txt', '/sample/random/folder/folder2/file-2.txt', '/otherfile/other-3.txt']
```